# Inefficiency of LP model in PuLP

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I have a problem of inefficiency with my LP model. In particular I have modeled, by means of PuLP, the problem of courier planning problem. I have a number of items, a number of couriers, the maximum capacity for each courier, the size of each item and the distances from a distribution point to the next and I need to assign the item for each courier such that the capacity constraint is satisfied. My objective is to minimize the maximum distance travelled by the couriers. In particular this is my model:

```
    def set_constraints_model1(self, data):
    """
    :param data: data of the instance
    :return: model structures
    """

    # Instance retrieval
    couriers, items, courier_size, item_size, distances = data

    # General variables
    asg = [[[LpVariable(name=f'asg_{k}-{i}-{j}', cat=LpBinary)
             for i in range(items)]
             for j in range(items)]
             for k in range(couriers)]

    weigths = [LpVariable(name=f'weigth_{i}', lowBound=0, upBound=courier_size[i], cat=LpInteger)
               for i in range(couriers)]

    # Distances computation variables
    dist1 = [
        LpVariable(name=f'or_to_first_{i}', lowBound=0, upBound=np.max(distances), cat=LpInteger)
        for i in range(couriers)]

    dist2 = [LpVariable(name=f'last_to_or_{i}', lowBound=0, upBound=np.max(distances), cat=LpInteger)
             for i in range(couriers)]

    dist2_bool = [[LpVariable(name=f'dist2_bool_{k}-{i}', cat=LpBinary)
                   for i in range(items)]
                   for k in range(couriers)]

    dist3 = [LpVariable(name=f'other_dist_{i}', lowBound=0, upBound=np.sum(distances), cat=LpInteger)
             for i in range(couriers)]

    obj_dist = [
        LpVariable(name=f'obj_dist{i}', cat=LpInteger, lowBound=np.min(distances), upBound=np.sum(distances))
        for i in range(couriers)]

    maximum = LpVariable(name=f'_maximum', lowBound=np.min(np.min(distances)), upBound=np.sum(distances), cat=LpInteger)

    self.model += maximum

    # Distances constraints

    # 1 ) Origin to first distribution center distance
    for k in range(couriers):
        self.model += dist1[k] == LpAffineExpression([
            (asg[k][0][i], distances[items][i])
            for i in range(items)])

    # 2 ) Last distribution center to Origin distance
    for k in range(couriers):
        self.model += lpSum(dist2_bool[k]) <= 1
        for i in range(items - 1):
            self.model += dist2_bool[k][i] - (lpSum(asg[k][i]) - lpSum(asg[k][i + 1])) == 0
        self.model += dist2_bool[k][-1] - lpSum(asg[k][-1]) == 0

    for k in range(couriers):
        self.model += LpAffineExpression([
            (self.linear_prod(dist2_bool[k][i], asg[k][i][j], 3, f'second_dist{k}-{j}-{i}'), distances[j][items])
            for i in range(items)
            for j in range(items)]) == dist2[k]

    # 3 ) Distances between all the distribution centers
    for k in range(couriers):
        self.model += LpAffineExpression([
            (self.linear_prod(asg[k][i][j], asg[k][i + 1][l], 3, f'items_dist{i}-{j}-{k}-{l}'), distances[j][l])
            for j in range(items)
            for l in range(items)
            for i in range(items - 1)]) == dist3[k]

    for k in range(couriers):
        self.model += obj_dist[k] == dist1[k] + dist2[k] + dist3[k]

    for el in obj_dist:
        self.model += maximum >= el

    # Each item must be carried once
    for i in range(items):
        self.model += lpSum(asg[k][j][i] for j in range(items) for k in range(couriers)) == 1

    # Each row must contain at most one value different from zero
    for k in range(couriers):
        for i in range(items):
            self.model += lpSum(asg[k][i]) <= 1

    # Force all the items to be in the first lines
    for k in range(couriers):
        for i in range(items - 1):
            self.model += lpSum(asg[k][i]) >= lpSum(asg[k][i + 1])

    # Weigths constraints
    for k in range(couriers):
        self.model += weigths[k] == LpAffineExpression([
            (asg[k][i][j], item_size[j])
            for i in range(items)
            for j in range(items)])



    return asg, weigths, obj_dist, couriers, items, distances
```

The main idea behind this model is to have a matrix for each courier (asg in the code), the size of this matrix is items x items, such that asg[k,i,j] = 1 if and only if the courier k carries the item in column j. So for each matrix I am going to have some rows with just a 1 and some other rows with all zero's, follows an example:

```
    [1,0,0,0]
    [0,0,1,0]
    [0,1,0,0]
    [0,0,0,0]
```

The courier associated with the above matrix will carries the item 0,3,2. I imposed constraints such that force all the items to be in the first lines and that each item must be carried.
In my model I created 4 more structures, dist1,dist2,dist2_bool and dist3. dist1,dist2,dist3 are vectors of length = couriers which are going to save respectively the distance from the origin to the first item, the distance from the last item to the origin and dist3 the distances between all the distribution points visited; dist2_bool is useful to know what is the index of the row of the last item carried by the courier k  (I remark that each courier must start and end in the origin). Finally the distance matrix is of the following form:

```
0 3 4 5 6 6 2 
3 0 1 4 5 7 3 
4 1 0 5 6 6 4 
4 4 5 0 3 3 2 
6 7 8 3 0 2 4 
6 7 8 3 2 0 4  
2 3 4 3 4 4 0
```

where the last row indicates the distance from the origin to distributions (items) 0,1,2,3,4,5 and the last column indicates the distances from the distributions(items) to the origin.

The problem of this model is that is slow, I guess that the problem of this model being slow is the constraint defined by the comment '# 3 ) Distances between all the distribution centers', because I need to find the couples of 1s in order to get the corresponding distance, with a complexity of: couriers * items^3.

Are there any smart decisions I can take to improve this model?

Comment: Would it help to turn `asg[k]` from a matrix to a set that only contains the non-zero positions? You example `asg` matrix would become the `set([(0,0), (1,2), (1,1)])` (first index is 0-based row, second index is 0-based column). This set indicates where the 1's are in that matrix. Anything not a 1 implicitly is a 0. With this you only have to iterate of the actual 1's when building the expressions.